# PSQL: use Where clause inside a called Trigger

Tags: postgresql, triggers

i want to execute a Trigger after every 'DELETE' operation on the table 'table1', because i need to delete the corresponding row in 'table2', too.

So i want to type:

```
DELETE * FROM table1 WHERE x;
```

And the Trigger should do the following in addition to the above delete operation:

```
DELETE * FROM table2 WHERE x;
```

So how can i access/reuse the 'WHERE' clause inside the trigger?

P.S.: I got the same problem with the `UPDATE` operation, but i think the solution will be the same...

P.P.S: More context for you: I have one table which stores some encrypted data and another table which stores the encryption-keys. So if someone deletes a row in table1 i want to delete all corresponding key-rows in table2 (there could be 1 for every user who has access to this row).

Thanks for you help :)

Comment: No. you cannot reuse your `WHERE` statement inside a trigger, You will only have access to the deleted row (if your trigger triggers `BEFORE DELETE`). But you certainly can do it with stored procedures

Comment: So if i would use `BEFORE DELETE` i could recreate the `WHERE` statement, because i could see the primary-key of that row? That would be great. How can i access the row(s) which will be deleted? @gogaz

Comment: If you want only delete rows (not add or update) then just use foreign keys between tables with ON DELETE CASCADE

Comment: I will use that to delete the rows, but unfortunately i want to use the `UPDATE` operation, too.